# Read-only versus read-write transactions

Tags: spring, transactions

It looks like a common problem, but I haven't seen much things on it.

For what I've read, it looks like a read-only transaction can read only commited data, so I guess that read-write transactions can read what is not yet commited.

Is it right ? What are the best practices ?

Comment: What transactions are you talking about? Is it about `readOnly` attribute of `@Transactional`, or what?

Comment: In Spring, yes, but the question is more general. I think I have also mixed up stuff with transaction isolation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring, this is dependent on how transactions are implemented and in case of databases what isolation level has been configured. Be aware that this is different between different RDBMS.